# CakePHP - can't get session variable in view

Tags: php, session, cakephp

In ProjectsController.php I'm setting a session variable as I'd like that info to be accessible in ALL controllers, models and views:

```
$this->Session->write('Project.title', $this->Project->title);
```

Now, when I try access it from Projects view, like this:

```
        <p>Project: <strong>
        <?php if (isset($session->read('Project.title'))): 
            $session->read('Project.title');
        ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            Not selected
        <?php endif; ?>
        </strong></p>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context
```

Which refers to the second line of above code.

I've been through CakePHP documentation and also searched SO, what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I've also tried using:

```
$this->Session->read('Project.title')
```

resulting in the same error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do what PHP tells you once in a while :)
The error message is pretty clear. You cannot use isset() and empty() this way.
They only work with variables direcly, not methods. So use

```
<?php if ($this->Session->check('Project.title')) {
    echo $this->Session->read('Project.title');
} ?>
```

as documented in the cookbook

you could also do

```
<?php
$title = $this->Session->read('Project.title');
if ($title) {
    echo $title;
} ?>
```

or even

```
<?php if ($title = $this->Session->read('Project.title')) {
    echo $title;
} ?>
```

the last one is not cakephp coding convention, though.

Comment: Yes Mark, I should definitely listen to it:)  This resolved it, thanks.

Comment: For a CakePHP 3.x solution refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/32668870

Answer (score 0):

`isset()` cannot deal with functions like that. Store the return value of that `$session` object's `read()` function, *then* test that variable inside the `if()` condition:

```
$title = $session->read('Project.title');
echo ($title) ? $title : '';
```